# Push notification when application is in background Xamarin IOS FireBase

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin

We are developping an application for our client, push notifications are done for Android (background & foreground) and iOS (foreground). But nothing is fired when the payload is sent from Firebase when the application is in background.

```cs
[Export("messaging:didReceiveRemoteNotification")]
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(
    UIApplication application,
    NSDictionary userInfo,
    Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    displayNotification("notif1");
}

[Export("messaging:didReceiveMessage:")]
public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    displayNotification("notif2");
}
```

```
{
  "validate_only": false,
  "message": {
    "data": {
      "action": "Create",
      "type": "A",
      "source": "WEB",
      "idDossier": "368",
      "idCartouche": "22953",
      "model": "{\"Id\":22953,\"...\":\"...\"}"
    },
    "notification": null,
    "android": null,
    "webpush": null,
    "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "apns-expiration": "0",
        "apns-priority": "10"
      },
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "alert": null,
          "badge": null,
          "sound": null,
          "content-available": 1,
          "mutable-content": 0,
          "category": null,
          "thread-id": null
        }
      }
    },
    "token": null,
    "topic": "d-368-u-77ffb0d907f04bfba8a0e3f35f7fd095",
    "condition": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `RegisterForRemoteNotifications` anywhere in your iOS app (i.e. before it enters a backgrounded state?)

Comment: Does this doc be helpful ? https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Firebase.CloudMessaging/component/GettingStarted.md#handle-messages-received-through-the-fcm-apns-interface

Comment: Yes I am calling `RegisterForRemoteNotifications`. And thanks for the doc, implemented `ReceiveRemoteNotification` but the notification popup only when the user open the app.

Comment: @Phobie Okey , do you have enable Remote Notifications as follow. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8rix.png

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes it's enabled in the Info.plist, and Push Notifications are enabled in the Entitlements.plist

Comment: @Phobie Okey, got it. I will check it, if have idea will share here.